Can having a external tube to measure water level near the pump a good idea?
Will a setup like the one below work?
I'm concerned when the water pump is switched on, the water inside the level indicator tube will be emptied-out and would produce a false reading.


Diameter and length of the intake pipe, and position of the sight gauge tube on the intake pipe, and flow rate of the pump would be required for specific calculations of error. But if it's not built yet, then there are better ways to gauge the level.

It depends on the friction head in the intake pipe. It's not the best location for a sight gauge tube, which would better be on the tank itself. The sight gauge lacking any valves for maintenance is also going to be a problem. But if the valve between the tube connection and the tank is wide open, the intake pipe is large diameter, and the distance to the tank is short, the friction head should be fairly insignificant, so there's not a large error. Now, if the valve were partially or fully  closed, the pipe is heavily corroded or silted, or the pipe is much longer than illustrated, there could be an issue.
A common solution used on large water tanks that does not involve the potential leaks of a sight tube is a float connected to a cable that runs out the top, over a pulley, and down to an indicator. That reads "full" when the indicator is at the bottom of the tank, (float at the top) and empty when the indicator is at the top of the tank (float at the bottom.)

I've seen such a cable operated gauge on municipal tank in Brisbane Australia but they zig-zagged the cable and attached a pointer on the rising section and camouflaged the counterweight to make the pointer follow movement of the float... this was probably cheaper than educating the audience.

A simple orifice can dampen movement in and out of the pipe...

Potential Issues:
Pump Suction:
If the tube is connected directly to the pump's suction line, it could introduce air into the system, reducing the pump's efficiency or even causing it to lose prime.
Water Hammer:
When the pump shuts off, the water in the tube could rush back into the well or tank, creating a shockwave known as water hammer. This can damage pipes and fixtures.
Tube Size:
The tube needs to be large enough to allow water to flow freely without creating a significant pressure drop in the system.
Maintenance:
The tube and its connection points need to be regularly checked for leaks or blockages.
Alternatives:
Float Switch:
A float switch is a more reliable way to monitor water levels and can be used to automatically turn the pump on and off as needed.
Pressure Gauge:
A pressure gauge can also be used to indirectly measure water level based on the pressure in the system.
Electronic Level Sensors:
These sensors use various technologies (ultrasonic, capacitive, etc.) to measure water level and can be connected to a control panel or alarm system.
While using an external tube to measure water level is possible, it may not be the most practical or reliable solution. Consider the potential issues and explore the alternative methods mentioned above. If you choose to proceed with the tube method, be sure to research proper installation and maintenance procedures to ensure the safety and efficiency of your plumbing system.
